# Microsoft VBA search function I programmed only works with 4 digit numbers (not an integer problem)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've programmed a search function using a user form and text box in Microsoft VBA and it works as I intend in all aspects save that it doesn't work for numbers with more than 4 digits. Initially I didn't worry because the site I'm working in doesn't have properties greater than 4 digits but Management is impressed with the excel as a whole and wish to integrate it into other sites where numbers with 5 digits are a property (sorry if I'm being a bit vague, it's company data it searches).

Evaluating my code, the only possible causes I can see is either with the line

If UCase(Sheet3.Cells(row_no, field).Value >= UCase(Me.Textbox1.Value) Then ...

Or it could be due to how textboxes operate in the user form (I feel like they might be treated as integers, but I'm not sure, I haven't been able to find anything online suggesting as such).

Any help would be appreciated. If the issue can't be assessed and fixed from the information I've given then simply inform me and I'll take down the post and reassess.

I replaced all variables as Integers as variables as Long but it did not fix the problem. Researched online for possible causes or solutions but have not been able to find any.

Comment: The `Value` property of a TextBox returns a Variant holding a String of the contents of the TextBox ... it is not numeric (Integer or otherwise) though obviously you can (and sounds like you have) converted it to a numeric. It's hard to otherwise help you with your question without seeing more of your 'search' code and seeing the data being searched so perhaps you could update your question?

Comment: Yeah that was it JohnM, initially I had the search function for string values and when I expanded it to include numerical ranges I thought I had everything changed to accommodate that but I forgot UCase turns it into a string. Changed it to CLng and works perfect now, thank you.

Comment: Great ... so if either of the answers added by others worked for you then if possible you should select the check mark icon for it so others can see the answer you used (helps keep the focus on the newer, unanswered questions)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague.

This scenario compares the value 10 in cell A1, with the value 10 in textbox1.
[image]

The code compares *text* 10 in the textbox, to the *number* 10 in cell A1 and returns False.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox Me.TextBox1 = Sheet1.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Converting the textbox value to a number returns True:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox CLng(Me.TextBox1) = Sheet1.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

or, converting the sheet number to text also returns True:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox Me.TextBox1 = CStr(Sheet1.Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

I expect you want the first example as you seem to want to see if one number is greater than the other.

Comment: Type conversion on user inputs should probably include input-validation.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII I agree, they should - working on an Access form myself where the format of the employee number depends on the employer, the start date can't be earlier or equal to a previous start date.... so many things to consider.  I was just answering the question asked, whether the input is valid or not would be a different question.  Depending on the requirements it might be useful to limit what's typed in as it's typed:  [VBA Numbers only in Textbox](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-numbers-only-in-textbox.746902/)

Answer (score 1):

What type do you think the value of a TEXTbox is? - It is a String, so unless you convert it into an int/long etc. it will stay a string. (Converting; either with a function like `CLng()` (explicit conversion) or by assigning the value to a variable that has the appropriate type (implicit conversion).

When comparing values you have to be careful that they are the right type. This is because strings are compared differently than numbers. For example `"34" > "1000"` is TRUE.

So make sure you convert your types to the ones you need (in your case numeric types like int and long).

You have to be careful though. Especially with user input. If you try to convert a string that can not be represented as a number you'll get a runtime error. To prevent this from happening you should use the function `IsNumeric()` before you convert. This way you can make sure that the user input will not produce an error when trying to convert (A simple example below)

```
Sub test(userInput As String)
    Dim i As Long
    
    If IsNumeric(userInput) Then
        i = CLng(userInput)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Pleas provide a number")
    End If
End Sub
```

You can check at any point in your code (as long as it's before the conversion and after the value can no longer be changed)

Comment: Yeah that was it, initially I had the search function for string values and when I expanded it to include numerical ranges I thought I had everything changed to accommodate that but I forgot UCase turns it into a string. Changed it to CLng and works perfect now, thank you.